# Print to PDF an email dropped into a Finder folder

Tags: finder, email, pdf

I need to record correspondence in projects and by default store everything as PDF files. I do the same with emails - I save the attachments in the relevant project folder, then copy the actual email message to the same folder, and then also print the email message itself to the folder.

What I need is a script that will notice when I drop an email into a folder, and then automatically save the email as a PDF into the same folder (using the subject as file name).

If it can be done that all the attachments are also saved to the same folder as part of the same script, I will be very happy.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Just to clarify, the Folder is not located inside your email ?

Comment: What email client are you using? Outlook ?

Comment: The folder is a Finder folder. It is not any particular folder, where I drop the email depends on the type of email it is. 

I am using Apple Mail

Answer (score 1):

I think you may want to investigate Hazel.

http://www.noodlesoft.com/hazel.php

It allows you to create automated workflows and is probably exactly what you need.

Comment: ADVERTISEMENT ? there is a Automator?